# How can I quiesce the cassandra database?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0

Is there any prebuilt command that I can use to quiesce the Cassandra db?

I am stuck on this.

Comment: I don't think there is pre-built way.

Comment: @chaitan64arun

So when I run nodetool snapshot command, 
Cassandra will quiesce the db in someway before taking a snapshot right ??????

Or I am missing something ?

Comment: What end effect are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: @Aaron I have stored my Cassandra Data on SAN Storage.
Now I do not want to use the Cassandra's inbuilt Snapshot but build my own Backup mechanism , so I want to quiesce the cassandra cluster before I take a backup.

I hope I have conveyed what I want to do properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By quiesce, I assume a pause/flush of data to disk.  There is a nodetool flush command that takes the data that is in memory and flushes it to SStables.  This also happens when a nodetool snapshot is taken.  Hope that helps.

Adam

Comment: Yes
By quiesce I meant pause of the system to take consistent snapshots.

Comment: @Adam_Huston
Do you know for how long does the db is paused when we run a nodetool flush command?

Thanks

Comment: The flush is writing everything from memory to an SSTable. It's an almost instant action. Less than a second in most cases.